# Docker: find out by command line if and which shared drives are enabled

Tags: docker

Do you know if there is a way to find out by using the command line, if and which shared drives are enabled?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

[Windows - Git Bash] To find out which drives are shared:

```
cat C:/Users/[user]/AppData/Roaming/Docker/settings.json
```

[Windows - CMD prompt]

```
type C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json
```

Within the file, you'll find the JSON object you're looking for:

```
"SharedDrives": {
"C": true
},...
```

---

To find out which volumes are mounted on your host you can use the following commands:

```
docker volume ls
```

This will give you a list, for more details you can inspect a single volume

```
docker volume inspect 2d858a93d15a8e6903cccfe04cdf5576812df8697ca4e07edbbf40575873d33d
```

Which will return something similar to:

```
{
    "CreatedAt": "2020-02-24T08:35:57Z",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": null,
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/2d858a93d15a8e6903cccfe04cdf5576812df8697ca4e07edbbf40575873d33d/_data",
    "Name": "2d858a93d15a8e6903cccfe04cdf5576812df8697ca4e07edbbf40575873d33d",
    "Options": null,
    "Scope": "local"
}
```

Comment: @user1472131 I've edited my answer. A command for this doesn't exist, but you'll be able to get what you want from a file Docker creates. I doubt there will be further investment in this from Docker.